# Errors at Embedded Cassandra server startup

Tags: unit-testing, cassandra

I am trying to use EmbeddedCassandraService to instantiate a Cassandra server in my unit tests. But I am getting this error. Any idea what can be causing this?

> ERROR org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor - Fatal error:
>   null; Can't construct a java object for
>   tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=No
>   single argument constructor found for class
>   org.apache.cassandra.config.Config Bad configuration; unable to start
>   server

I used a configuration which is working in a standalone installation.

Answer (score 1):

This [thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/user@cassandra.apache.org/msg07272.html) and [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-1753) from the Cassandra users mailing list may help, as it reports the same error message - what version of Cassandra are you using?  (The bug report is against 0.7 beta 2)